# Groovy Script Error: No such property while parsing the json

Tags: testing, groovy, soapui

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaOog.png)Trying to extract the response property by parsing the JSON, receiving NoSuchProperty error

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def response = messageExchange.response.responseContext
def json1 = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
log.info json1.results[0].id
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo. Try:

```
def response = messageExchange.response.responseContent
```